# pygame.QUIT() - TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to python. I'm writing a code for a simple alien invasion game but I'm getting this error.

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
    ship = Ship(screen)
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT():
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
        ship.blitme()
        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

I'm aware that I'm accidentally calling some integer value but I have no clue where I'm going wrong.

I have also checked these lines

> File "C:/Users/Areeb Irfan/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/AlienGame.py", line 25, in 
> run_game()
> File "C:/Users/Areeb Irfan/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/AlienGame.py", line 16, in run_game
> gf.check_events(ship)
> File "C:\Users\Areeb Irfan.PyCharmCE2018.3\config\scratches\game_functions.py", line 5, in check_events
> if event.type==pygame.QUIT():
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I have used 3 more modules named game_functions, ship, settings.

Comment: you have clue in error message - it shows you line with problem. If you see word "collable" then you have problem with `()`

Comment: `pygame.QUIT` is integer value, not function. You can't use `()` with `pygame.QUIT`

Comment: Replace `event.type==pygame.QUIT()` with `event.type==pygame.QUIT`

Comment: You can see this by the way in the last line of the traceback.

Comment: you have three lines but only one error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Lines show which functions were called before it get problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in your error message, this line `event.type==pygame.QUIT()` is the issue. The error `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` means that you are trying to call an int, which means that you are trying to treat an int as a function, which in turn means that you have parentheses `()` after an int value. The only place you have parentheses in that line is afer `pygame.QUIT`, so just remove the parentheses:

```
if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix that, remove the parentheses () at pygame.QUIT.
Get rid of them, and run the code again. It should work, as long as you don't have that same "if" somewhere else.

Comment: From what I can tell, you are saying the same thing as the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57136641/15368978). Maybe edit to clarify how yours is different?

Answer (score 0):

There is a flaw in your code. You have written as:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
        quit()
```

Better try using this code:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
        quit()
```

(or)

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
        sys.exit()
```

This happens because pygame.QUIT is an integer data. Integer data is not followed by parantheses. But enclosing it with parantheses makes it to be a function which is wrong. Hope this helps you!